# How to deserialize a JSON string in java when using VS code?

Tags: java, json

I am coding a simple java project in VS code and I want to deserialize the JSON string I receive from an API. How can I do it? Can I do it by downloading an extension?

Comment: It is a duplicate. The fact that VSC was mentioned is entirely irrelevant and just an instance of the XY problem. And no, you can't use an editor extension to parse JSON in your Java code???

Comment: @LMD What I think OP is asking for is something in the lines of a maven extension for installing plugins. In this case, a plugin for parsing JSON data. Like in IntelliJ, you can browse and download extensions. I think that's what OP is looking for, hence why Vs Code is relevant. Could be wrong tho.